# How to join two vectors' elements in a list and keep names according to origin vector?

Tags: r, list

I'm trying to find an elegant way to link function parameters and an `httr`'s call query list. Assume we have two character vectors, indicating animals and colors

```
animals = "dog"
colors = "red"
```

If I use the query parameter

```
list(animal=animals,color=colors)
```

it will produce the expected result. On the other hand, if I want multiple parameters for one of the components

```
animals = c("dog","cat")
```

the same list would create

```
$animal
[1] "dog" "cat"

$color
[1] "red"
```

when `httr` requires a list like

```
$animal
[1] "dog"

$animal
[1] "cat"

$color
[1] "red"
```

How can I elegantly create the appropriate list, where instead of having a character vector as an element, multiple elements with the same name would be created?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
foo <- list(animals = c("dog","cat"), color = "red")
foo <- as.list(unlist(foo))
foo <- setNames(foo, gsub("[[:digit:]]", "", names(foo)))
```

The list becomes less useful since selecting by name doesn't work, but should be the format you want. Renaming isn't great if your list has numbers, but that might be something you have to work out separately.

**Update:**

I don't like renaming with regular expressions. You can also try something like this to remove that last line:

```
as.list(setNames(unlist(foo), rep(names(foo), sapply(foo, length))))
```

It's a little more exact that using `setNames` and `gsub`.

Comment: This is definitely better than my previous attempt.

Comment: Which function or parameter needs the list in this format?

Comment: `httr::GET`, the `query` parameter needs a list in this format.

Answer (score 0):

```
c(animals=as.list(animals),colors=colors)
$animals1
[1] "dog"

$animals2
[1] "cat"

$colors
[1] "red"
```